# How to trust a certificate authority in Java?

Tags: java, ssl, certificate, certificate-authority

My application connects to an SSL web service which uses a certificate to verify its identity. Recently, this certificate changed and since it is not signed by a trusted authority, part of my application failed. The service's advice to protect against this situation in the future is that I should start trusting the existing certificate's signing authority, instead of the individual certificates.

**How may this be achieved in Java?**

Currently I'm adding the certificate they provide into a keystore using keytool and composing it into a TrustManagerFactory something like:

```
public static TrustManager[] getTrustManagers() throws KeyStoreException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, CertificateException, IOException {
    KeyStore tks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
    tks.load(StarTrustManagerFactory.class.getResourceAsStream("webservice.ks"), "password".toCharArray());
    TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
    tmf.init(tks);
    return tmf.getTrustManagers();
};
```

Is there a way of adapting this approach to return a `TrustManager` which trusts the signing authority of the certificates I have? Additionally, how can I extract the information regarding the signer of the certificate from the certificate I have?

Thanks, Dan.

Comment: See http://javarevisited.blogspot.de/2012/09/difference-between-truststore-vs-keyStore-Java-SSL.html - you trust any certificate included in your truststore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that code posted worked before the certificate changed, leave it as is. Instead modify the webservice.ks keystore and import the <s>intermediate and</s> root ca certificates of the site you are connecting to.

You can get these certificates by visiting the address in a web browser and saving them to disk. For how you'd do this in firefox, see https://superuser.com/a/97203/172370. However at step 4 in the linked instructions, select the root<s>/intermediate</s> ca certs to export (click in the certificate hierarchy box on the desired one).

Then assuming the .ks file is a jks keystore, use keytool to import the certificates into the keystore.

Update: ignore what I said about the intermediate certificate, you shouldn't need it (see [Does a truststore need the sub-ca certificate?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/353010/241294)). Just import the root ca certificate.

Comment: Thanks. I see now how it should work. Unfortunately, with the certificate I get from accessing the web service with a browser, it is alone in its certificate hierarchy. So I should go back to them and ask them for the CA's certificate or the root/intermediary? Just clarifying the terminology I should use. Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like either the certificate wasn't generated by a CA or their web server isn't configured correctly. You may need to raise this with the web service admins.